# MySQL trigger - insert in another table only when data is different

Tags: mysql, triggers

I want to insert data in another table only when the data is different.
So for this I created a trigger on the first table, like this:

```
CREATE TRIGGER `RegistrationHistory` AFTER UPDATE ON `registration`
FOR EACH ROW
INSERT INTO registration_history (`Key`, `Name`, `Version`, `LastUpdate`)
SELECT OLD.Key, OLD.Name, OLD.Version, NOW()
WHERE OLD.Key != NEW.Key
AND OLD.Name != NEW.Name
AND OLD.Version != NEW.Version
```

The problem is that it errors out with:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near 'WHERE OLD.Key != NEW.Key

I noticed that if I try this doesn't work either:

```
SELECT 'ACBDE'
WHERE 1 = 1
```

So how should I insert into the history table using MySQL only when there is a difference?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try wrapping in an if statement:

```
CREATE TRIGGER `RegistrationHistory` AFTER UPDATE ON `registration`
FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
  IF (NEW.Key != OLD.Key AND NEW.Name != OLD.Name AND NEW.Version != OLD.Version) Then
    INSERT INTO registration_history (`Key`, `Name`, `Version`, `LastUpdate`)
        VALUES(NEW.Key, NEW.Name, NEW.Version, NOW());
  END IF;
END
```

Comment: The idea is very good, but unfortunately is not working. I have the error: #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 5

Comment: Try to add delimiters - DELIMITER $$ CREATE TRIGGER...BEGIN...END$$ DELIMITER ;